# Compare the same column in 2 rows of a same table with each other

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a oracle database and I have the following table with data of documents. I can add the same document with different revision. So that the keys would be doc_id and revision. There can be as many as revisions for a given document.

| doc_id | revision | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | test1 |
| A | 2 | test2 |
| A | 3 | test3 |
| B | 1 | new1 |
| B | 2 | new2 |

I want to create a view comparing data column with each revision of the document. The output of the view should be like below.

| doc_id | compared_revision | old_data | new_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1-2 | test1 | test2 |
| A | 1-3 | test1 | test3 |
| A | 2-3 | test2 | test3 |
| B | 1-2 | new1 | new2 |

Please help me with creating such view. If this is not possible with the given data set, please suggest me a workaround.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it (without needing to perform a self-join or scan the table twice) using a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT doc_id,
       PRIOR revision || '-' || revision AS compared_revision,
       PRIOR data AS old_data,
       data AS new_data
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR doc_id   = doc_id
AND    PRIOR revision < revision
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( doc_id, revision, data ) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 'test1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 'test2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 'test3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 'new1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 'new2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DOC_ID | COMPARED_REVISION | OLD_DATA | NEW_DATA
> :----- | :---------------- | :------- | :-------
> A      | 1-2               | test1    | test2   
> A      | 1-3               | test1    | test3   
> A      | 2-3               | test2    | test3   
> B      | 1-2               | new1     | new2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb743b6a90a60980925c5ffc203d58cc)*

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple self-join:

```
select t1.doc_id, (t1.revision || '-' || t2.revision) as compared_revision, t1.data, t2.data
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.doc_id = t2.doc_id and t1.revision < t2.revision
order by t1.doc_id, compared_revision;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e65f346c72513e1b6eebf21dbb370082) is a db<>fiddle.